# Can not install Mono Runtime 2.10.11 on my OSX 10.8.5 macs.

Tags: mono, runtime

I have a program that I need to run and it requires Runtime 2.10.11. I can download and run the installer until install is complete but when I open the program I need to run, I get an error warning saying that Mono Runtime 2.10.11 is required, otherwise the program may not run correctly. The program does open but as soon as I enter a command, it disappears and shuts down. I have the security preferences set so the program does install or at least it says it does. But I cannot find the Mono.framework folder anywhere on the computer and not in the root library folder.

Kevin

Answer (score 0):

If you are the user of that program, you might download Mono Runtime from

http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.11/macos-10-x86//MonoFramework-MRE-2.10.11.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg

or Mono SDK from

http://download.mono-project.com/archive/2.10.11/macos-10-x86//MonoFramework-MDK-2.10.11.macos10.xamarin.x86.dmg

About whether Runtime or SDK should be used, you have to refer to the readme file of that program, or consult its developer.

If you are a developer, you should avoid such scenarios for your end users by switching to Xamarin.Mac. That solution gives you a chance to embed Mono into the program, so that at deployment end users don't need to install Mono separately. Also Xamarin.Mac enabled apps can be uploaded to Mac App Store,

http://xamarin.com/mac